# First Database Schema - Producing an error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(900) NOT NULL,
    company_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company (id),
    date datetime NOT NULL,
    source_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES source (id),
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES location (id)
);

CREATE TABLE location (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    coordinate varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES country (id)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE company (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE source (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
);
```

It is telling me that there is invalid syntax on line four on http://sqlfiddle.com when I put it in and click build schema. I can see no error, can anyone shed some light please?

Also if I have done anything poorly or made any bad decisions please let me know.

Comment: Is this mysql or postgresql?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I didnt realise it made a difference. It is postgresql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 faulty commas. One at the end of "CREATE TABLE company", "CREATE TABLE source".
And create country before location.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE location (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    coordinate varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES country (id)
);

CREATE TABLE source (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(900) NOT NULL,
    company_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company (id),
    date timestamp NOT NULL,
    source_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES source (id),
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES location (id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but this still produces the same error

Comment: I fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Can you tell me what it was so I can learn for next time please?

Comment: Edited again, now it's OK for postgres. First, the order of the tables were wrong. You have to create the referencing table at last. Second, AUTO_INCREMENT and DATETIME does not exist in postgres, it's SERIAL and TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 2):

You must create the tables before you can reference them elsewhere. Create your tables in this order:
Source,
Company,
Country,
Location,
Item

Note that you may do the first three in any order, but Country must come before Location, and Location, Source, and Company must come before Item.

You also have two extra commas at the end of the definitions of Source and Company. You must remove those.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the `country` table before referring to it `location` table.
2. Remove the dangling `,` in the definitions of `company`  and `source`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create table `country` then `location` followed by `company`,`source` and at the last `item`.